# Delete items in Cosmos DB with spare RUs

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We use Cosmos DB to track all our devices and also data that is related to the device (and not stored in the device document itself) is stored in the same container with the same partition ID.

Both the device document and the related documents have `/deviceId` as the partition key. When a device is removed, then I remove the device document. I actually want to remove the entire partition, but this doesn't seem to be possible. So I revert to a query that queries for all items with this partition key and remove them from the database.

This works fine, but may consume a lot of RUs if there is a lot of related data (which may be true in some cases). I would rather just remove the device and schedule all related data for removal later (it doesn't hurt to have them in the database for a while). When RU utilization is low, then I start removing these items. Is there a standard solution to do this?

The best solution would be to schedule this and that Cosmos DB would process these commands when it has spare RUs, just like with the TTL deletion. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

A feature is now in preview to delete all items by partition key using fire and forget background processing model with a limited amount of available throughput. There's a signup link in the [feature request page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/17296813-add-the-ability-to-delete-all-data-in-a-partition) to get access to preview.

Currently, the API looks like a new `DeleteAllItemsByPartitionKey` method in the SDK.

Comment: +1. yes, this was the feature I mentioned in my response. Ramon, If you're ok with using a very early preview version this can be an option.

Answer (score 3):

It definitely is possible to set a TTL and then let Cosmos handle expiring data out of the container when it is idle. However, the cost to update the document in the first place is about what it costs to delete it anyway so you're not gaining much.

An approach as you suggest, may be to have a separate container (or even a queue) where you insert a new item with the deviceId to retire. Then in the evenings or during a time when you know the system is idle. Run a job that reads the next deviceId in the queue, queries for all the items with that partition key, then deletes the data or sets the TTL to expire the data.

There is a feature to delete an entire partition in the works that would be perfect for this scenario (in fact, it's designed for it) but no ETA on availability.